# Using a var based on an enum in a Where clause in Entity Framework throws an exception

Tags: .net, entity-framework, enums, where-clause

I have the following code which throws an exception (detail in code comments below). I am merely trying to use an instance of an enum as part of the Where clause. I understand the message, but I don't understand why EF cannot parse an Int32 enum.

It works if I copy the enum to an Int32 and then filter on that, but it seems very messy.

```
    Enum MyEnum As Int32
    Zero
    One
    Two
End Enum
Shared Function GetStuff(ByVal EnumValue As MyEnum) As IQueryable
    Dim Db As New MainDb
    Dim DetailList As IQueryable
    Dim MyInt As Int32 = EnumValue

    ' PostalProviderId is an Int column in SQL.
    'DetailList = From D In Db.DeliveryService Where D.PostalProviderId = EnumValue ' This fails.
    DetailList = From D In Db.DeliveryService Where D.PostalProviderId = MyInt ' This works.

    ' The following attempt to enumerate the results yields;
    ' **** System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
    ' **** Message = "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."
    ' **** Source = "System.Data.Entity"
    For Each Thingy In DetailList
        Console.WriteLine(Thingy.ToString())
    Next
    Return DetailList

End Function
```

Is there a more elegant solution than copying the enum values to a local int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the entity framework doesn't know how to eveluate your enum when it is building the T-SQL to get the int behind it.  The short answer is that you have to store it in a temp variable and use that.

Some more information can be found at:

http://gmontrone.com/post/problem-with-casting-enums-in-linq-to-entities.aspx

and

http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2008/02/26/entity-framework-comparison-frustration-explained.aspx

Comment: Bit of a naff bug that. Thanks.